# mysql logging error

Tags: mysql

Hi my mySql server crashed for some hours ago and now I can't start it again.
I am running this command to start mySql: `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start`
I got this error message when I run the command:

```
[....] Starting mysql (via systemctl): mysql.serviceJob for mysql.service failed. See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
failed!
```

the output of `systemctl status mysql.service`:

```
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: activating (start-post) since ons 2016-07-06 13:38:31 CEST; 1min 41s ago
  Process: 8062 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mysqld_safe (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 8059 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 8062 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS);         : 8063 (mysql-systemd-s)
   CGroup: /system.slice/mysql.service
           └─control
             ├─8063 /bin/bash /usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start post
             └─8768 sleep 1

jul 06 13:38:31 ubuntuServerEmil systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
jul 06 13:38:31 ubuntuServerEmil mysqld_safe[8062]: 160706 13:38:31 mysqld_safe Can't log to error log and syslog at the same time.  Remove all --log-error configuration options for --syslog to take effect.
jul 06 13:38:31 ubuntuServerEmil mysqld_safe[8062]: 160706 13:38:31 mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/log/mysql/error.log'.
jul 06 13:38:31 ubuntuServerEmil mysqld_safe[8062]: 160706 13:38:31 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
```

It looks like it is an logging error but how do I fix it?

UPDATE
Found the following error in the log: `/var/log/mysql/error.log`

```
2016-07-06 07:15:03 58630 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: unknown variable 'audit-log=ON'
```

Comment: You can try to reconfigure MuSQL. Use these commands: `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop` then `sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-5.5` or `sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server` then finally `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start`

Comment: I can't run the dpkg-reconfigure commands I got an error that mysql-server-5.5 is not installed and the same for mysql-server. I use Ubuntu server 15.04

Comment: What do you get when you type the command `mysql` on the terminal?

Comment: Actually I think I found the problem in the config file there was an error in a row after fixing that I can start the server again. I guess something made the server restart in the night and when it read the config file it get the error. Because the mysql server has run for some month now so I didn't thought that something I did for along time ago should create an error now. But now everything works fine again.

Comment: I found the real error in an log file where it sad this: `unknown variable 'audit-log=ON'`

Comment: Maybe you can edit your question to include this info about the `unknown variable 'audit-log=ON'` error, then write an answer on how you have solved it. Ping me for a +1 once done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I founded the error message in `/var/log/mysql/error.log`

```
2016-07-06 07:15:03 58630 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: unknown variable 'audit-log=ON'
```

Then I opened the config file `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` and founded a row with the statement `audit-log=ON` I deleted that row and tested to start the server again with `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start` the first time it did't work but after running `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start` again the MySql server started and working normally again.